# Establishing $\cos^2 4\alpha=\cos^2 2\alpha-\sin 6\alpha \sin 2\alpha$ without the use of Werner or prostaferesis formulas

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, education

I have this identity:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #138D75]{\cos^2 4\alpha=\cos^2 2\alpha-\sin 6\alpha \sin 2\alpha} \tag 1$$

If I write this like as:

$$(\cos 4\alpha+\cos 2\alpha)\cdot (\cos 4\alpha-\cos 2\alpha)=-\sin 6\alpha \sin 2\alpha$$

I can use Werner and prostaferesis formulas and I find the identity $(1)$.

But if we suppose of not to use these formulas I have done a try writing:

$$\cos^2 4\alpha=\cos^2 2\alpha-\sin 6\alpha \sin 2\alpha \tag 1$$

$$[\cos(2(2\alpha))]^2=(2\cos^2\alpha-1)^2-\sin 6\alpha \sin 2\alpha \tag 2$$

$$\cos^4 2\alpha -2\sin^2 2\alpha\cos^22\alpha+\sin^4 2\alpha=(2\cos^2\alpha-1)^2-\sin 6\alpha \sin 2\alpha \tag 3$$

Then I have abandoned because I should do long computations and I think that is not the right way.

> Is there any trick without to use the prostapheresis or Werner's formulas?

Comment: Where did these obscure names for addition laws in trigonometry come from? In my almost 68 years I've never seen anything like those.

Comment: @TedShifrin Wolfram? :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Are you referring to my bad English or was that your own personal observation :-) ?

Comment: @TedShifrin: If you mean "prosthaphaeresis", then note Wolfram Mathworld's ["Prosthaphaeresis Formulas" entry](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html). The term is also mentioned in Wikipedia's ["List of Trigonometric Identities" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities); the ["Prosthaphaeresis" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis) explains some history, noting that the term comes from the Greek *prosthesis* ("addition") and *aphaeresis* ("subtraction").

Comment: @Blue I'm agree with you: they are two greek words with two roots. +1 for the comment.

Comment: @Sebastiano: No comments whatsoever on your English. I didn't study (nor do I now) by reading Wiki or Wolfram.  I don't think there are too many mathematicians who use this arcane terminology, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin Don't worry with me absolutely :-). My English has a low level and it is true. I have 46 years old but I have always know these laws with the prosthaphaeresis formulas remembering the Greek language.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid any use, explicit or implicit, of the addition formulae for sine and cosine? That hardly seems possible.

A fairly natural proof, with $\beta = 2\alpha,$ is
\begin{gather*}
\sin3\beta\sin\beta = \sin(\beta + 2\beta)\sin\beta =
\sin^2\beta\cos2\beta + \sin\beta\cos\beta\sin2\beta \\
= \sin^2\beta(2\cos^2\beta - 1) + 2\sin^2\beta\cos^2\beta =
\sin^2\beta(4\cos^2\beta - 1) \\
= \sin^22\beta - \sin^2\beta = \cos^2\beta - \cos^22\beta.
\end{gather*}
But as Ted Shifrin says in his answer, that may be "forbidden fruit".

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Kind user can you delete, please, your comment and trasform it like an answer? Thus I vote it :-)

Comment: I'm reluctant to post an answer when I still don't feel I understand the question. :) P.S. You can always upvote my comment and make my day. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that we can establish the identity without too much work; it certainly isn't short though. Your statement is equivalent to $$\cos^2 4x-\cos^2 2x=-\sin 6x\sin2x$$We'll start with left hand side; my strategy will be to make everything in terms of $\cos 2x$. I will make use of the following identities:
$$\begin{align}
\sin^2\theta&\equiv1-\cos^2\theta\\
\cos2\theta&\equiv2\cos^2\theta-1\\
\sin3\theta&\equiv3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta
\end{align}$$
Here we go:
$$\begin{align}
\cos^2 4x-\cos^2 2x&\equiv(2\cos^2 2x-1)^2-\cos^22x\\
&\equiv4\cos^42x-5\cos^22x+1
\end{align}$$
Now for the right hand side:
$$\begin{align}
-\sin6x\sin2x&\equiv-\sin2x(3\sin2x-4\sin^3 2x)\\
&\equiv4\sin^42x-3\sin^2x\\
&\equiv4(1-\cos^22x)^2-3(1-\cos^22x)\\
&\equiv4(\cos^4 2x-2\cos^2x+1)-3+3\cos^22x\\
&\equiv4\cos^42x-5\cos^22x+1
\end{align}$$
Hence we have $$\cos^2 4x-\cos^2 2x\equiv-\sin 6x\sin2x$$ as required.

---

I personally would also be very interested in any shortcut or trick that could be used here instead; if you find one please let me know.

Comment: For me, it looks great. If I find a shorter one I'll let you know. I thank everyone from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: @Sebastiano no problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I have something a little more straightforward. If I am using some of the forbidden fruit, I apologize. First of all, as hamam already noted, I'm going to let $2\alpha = x$ to save my sanity. So I want to show that
$$\cos^2 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin 3x\sin x.$$
Aside from the double-angle formula for $\cos 2x$, I will need the triple angle formula
\begin{align*}
\cos 3x &= \cos 2x\cos x -\sin 2x\sin x \\ &= (2\cos^2 x-1)\cos x - 2\sin^2x\cos x \\ &= 2\cos^3 x-\cos x - 2(1-\cos^2 x)\cos x \\ &= 4\cos^3 x-3\cos x.
\end{align*}

Note that $\cos 2x=\cos (3x-x) = \cos 3x\cos x + \sin 3x\sin x$, so the original formula is equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
\cos^2x -\cos^2 2x + \cos3x\cos x = \cos 2x. \tag{$\star$}
\end{equation*}
Well, by the triple angle formula above,
\begin{align*}
\cos 2x+ \cos^2 2x - \cos^2 x &= (2\cos^2 x-1)+(2\cos^2 x -1)^2 - \cos^2  x \\ & = 4\cos^4x - 3\cos^2 x = \cos3x\cos x,
\end{align*}
and this establishes ($\star$).

Having looked carefully at A-level student's, he's using the triple angle formula for sin, so these solutions are almost surely equivalent. :)

Comment: I certainly vote your effort of your answer and more.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Put $$a=2\alpha$$
and prove simply that

$$\cos^2(2a)=\cos^2(a)-\sin(3a)\sin(a)$$

using

$$2\sin(3a)\sin(a)=$$
$$\cos(3a-a)-\cos(3a+a)$$

Comment: Aren't you using the Werner formulae?

Comment: With my mind I think they always come long calculations however I sincerely appreciate your hint.

Comment: Hi My friend of Torino. aaahhhaaah

Comment: Don't remind me of tonight's game: I'm an Inter fan ahahahah, but by now as a tired fan, Juventus merited to go to the final. :-):-)

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin^22\theta=4\sin^2\theta\ (1-\sin^2\theta)$$
$$=\sin\theta\ (\sin\theta+(3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta))$$
$$=\sin\theta\ (\sin\theta+\sin 3\theta)=\sin^2\theta+\sin 3\theta\sin \theta.$$
Therefore, $\cos^22\theta=\cos^2\theta-\sin 3\theta\sin\theta.$ Finally,
replace $\theta$ by $2\alpha.$

Comment: Thank you very much to have had also your answer. My best and sincere regards.